# How to use generic function to tear down swift's optional pyramid of doom

Tags: swift, generics, option-type

Instead of using multiple optional bindings, we can define a function to tear down optional pyramid of doom.

```
func if_let<T, U, V> (a: T?, _ b: U?, _ c: V?, fn:(T, U, V) -> () ){
    if let a = a {
        if let b = b {
            if let c = c {
                fn(a, b, c)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I can write like this:

```
var s1: String? = "s11"
var s2: String? = "s22"
var s3: String? = "s33"

if_let(s1, s2, s3) { s1, s2, s3 in
    print(("\(s1) - \(s2) - \(s3)"))
}
```

However, the problem is how to make this `if_let` function more generic so that it can accept any number of arguments. My implementation is like this:

```
func if_let<T> (values: T?..., fn:(params: [T]) -> ()) {
    for value in values {
        guard value != nil else { return }
    }
    let unwrappedArray = values.map{ $0! }
    fn(params: unwrappedArray)
}
```

I tried to map the array and get a new one with all elements unwrapped and then call the `fn`. But when I ran the test again, I got a compile error:

> Cannot convert value of type `String?` to expected argument type '_?'

Can anyone explain and fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your second implementation of `if_let` no longer takes as a final parameter a function of type `(T,U,V)->()`. It now needs a function of type `([T])->()`. If you call it with one, it compiles:

```
if_let(s1, s2, s3) { args in // or: (args: [String])->() in
    print("\(args[0]) - \(args[1]) - \(args[2])")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A relevant note, rather than an answer to the specific question: with Swift 2, you needn't enter the pyramid of doom no more

```
let a: String? = nil
let b: Int? = nil
let c: Double? = nil

// possible mutate...

if let a = a, b = b, c = c {
    // do something with shadow vars
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot this. The blog I read is not in swift2. Thank you for your reminder. But can you explain why I got the compile error above